# How to write compile and run with one command in vim

Tags: c, vim

So I have my config file .vimrc that has this code which should save the file compile and run it when I press F3. This doesn't work.

```
map <F3> ^M:w^M:!gcc *.c -g; ./a.out^M
```

Comment: Any reason you're using `^M` instead of `<enter>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your keymapping worked for me (assuming you type `^M` as e.g. Ctrl-V Ctrl-M).

If you have a makefile setup (and you probably should) you can just use `:make`.

You can set the `makeprg` option if you use something other than `make`, e.g. `cmake` `scons` `ant` or something else.

Comment: @user594546: In my experience, compiling all the `*.c` files in the current directory into a executable is only a sustainable build process for a very short time in a project. You need something a bit more scalable before very long.

Answer (score 3):

The first `^M` is wrong. Change the others to `<enter>`:

```
map <F3> :w<enter>:!gcc *.c -g; ./a.out<enter>
```

Comment: +1 for :w<enter>. However, for a single file, you'd better use ":!gcc %:p"

Answer (score 1):

How are you writing `^M`?  You can write it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or better still, change it to `<CR>` which doesn't require any special tricks.

Answer (score 0):

also it's not necessary to compile `*.c` and to run `a.out`,
`%` and `%:r` can be used instead

```
map <F3> :w<enter>:!gcc % -o %:r;./%:r<enter>
```

or

```
map <F3> :w<enter>:!make;./%:r<enter>
```